# Force QWebEngine to use software rendering

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.5, qtwebengine, webengine

I'm using QWebEngine to display some webpages. Unfortunately it uses OpenGL internally - which leads to a crash on some graphics adapters (one can see the driver-DLL as the reason for the crash easily). As a second caveat it is not possible to catch this crash by a try-catch-block.

So my question: how can one force QWebEngine to use software rendering only and to not to use OpenGL?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just compile a version of the Qt library without OpenGL?

Comment: @Flovdis If the feature is available somehow why would you compile a customized version of the Qt library? This is an insane overhead and if there is another way I sure will go for it instead of this.

Comment: @flovdis because this would force the whole Qt environment to use software rendering which is not intended. for my own OpenGL-based applications I can easily check if it works or not and avoid any of these functions, only QWebengine is stupid enough to assume everything is fine - which leads to a crash. so I only want qWebEngine to use software rendering but not all the other Qt application

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're on Windows, and are using the official Qt binaries, and are using Qt 5.5 or newer. These allow [to switch between Desktop OpenGL, ANGLE (Direct X) and software rasterization at runime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers).

It should be therefore enough to set the QT_OPENGL environment variable to either "angle" (to use the DirectX backend) or "desktop". To hardcode this you can set the Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES or Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL application attributes.

If you use WebEngine through Qt Quick, you can also use the [Qt Quick 2D renderer](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuick2DRenderer/).

Comment: I'm on Windows, but Windows 7 Embedded - where the whole detection of graphics platform via Qt does not work (as I found out recently). And I'm working with self-compiled binaries (option -opengl dynamic). So I really would need an option to force just QWebEngine to software rendering, not the whole environment.

Comment: @Elmi did you find a solution for this in the end? We have the same issue here, an OpenGL application that used to use WebKit to show a webpage. Moving to 5.6 requires to update to WebEngine but just creating a QWebPage, without even trying to load a page is causing a crash on some systems. I couldn't isolate what was the cause, we've had crashes on AMD and NVidia cards. Sometimes updating the graphics drivers solves the issue, sometimes not. Forcing *just QWebEngine* to use software rasterization sounds like a good idea. Any help very welcome...

Comment: @Uflex unfortunately not, QWebEngine is an instable piece of crap, it is a shame it was released in this poor state...

Comment: @Elmi it would seem that in our case we were just missing some dependencies. Running WinDeployQt showed the missing files. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35448081/831673) for more info. I'm not sure why it was working on some machines but not others though...